# mysqli_error() connection info

Tags: php, mysqli

I am converting PHP code from mysql_ to mysqli_.  My DB connection is in a separate file, named "conn.inc" in a parent folder of my regular code.  The code in it is ::

```
function GetDBConn($host="localhost", $user="mydb", $pass="mypass", $db="mydb")   {

    return $dbconn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_close($dbconn);

}
```

In my code files, I have 
`include_once ("../conn.inc");` .

I have code like -

```
$AuditInsertQ = mysqli_query(GetDBConn(),"INSERT INTO audit (userid, notes) VALUES (\"".$userid."\",  \"".$notes."\")") or die("Error inserting row to Audit: ".mysqli_error($dbconn));
```

When I run the code, I get a message that ::

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbconn in C:\...
```

All of the examples I have seen have the DB connection in the same file as the code it was referencing.  How do I reference the DB connection when it is in a different file; I thought the "include_once" was the way...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much wrong in this code I don't even know where to start.

- no need for `mysqli_error()` at all
- no need for a function like `GetDBConn()`
- `mysqli_close()` right after connect makes no sense. Thanks to return operator, it never gets called though
- `die()` is harmful
- `@` operator is harmful
- the file extension for conn.inc is harmful
- the way you are adding variables to your query is most harmful of them all

I know it's hard to find a good tutorial. Internet is full of crappy outdated information. I am writing good tutorials, but Google don't know they are good and don't show them to you. Well at least I can give it to you here in my answer.

Three things you must understand about modern mysqli

- mysqli can report its errors automatically, no need for `mysqli_error()`
- a connection must be made only once, it means there is no use for a function like this
- no variable should be added to the query directly. You have to use prepared statements with placeholders for the purpose.

In order to fix your code,

- please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/285587). It doesn't explain why you should use prepared statements but take my word for it
- then read my tutorial on [how to connect with mysqi properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)
- rename your file to conn.php or anyone will be able to see your database credentals

Then rewrite your code to

```
include_once ("../conn.php");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO audit (userid, notes) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid,$notes);
$stmt->execute();
```

For the explanation on what is going on in this code please see my tutorial on [how to run an INSERT query with mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert)

Answer (score 0):

In you function `GetDBConn` it return a mysql resource, not define a `$dbconn` variable for you.

Use something like `mysqli_query($dbconn = GetDBConn(),"INSERT INTO audit ....`

---

**Note**

```
function GetDBConn($host="localhost", $user="mydb", $pass="mypass", $db="mydb")   {

    return $dbconn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_close($dbconn);

}
```

`$dbconn` is only avaliable in the function, it cannot be accessed outside the function, so define it here is useless.
`mysqli_close($dbconn);` will never reached.